# In Python 3.5, is the keyword "await" equivalent to "yield from"?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, generator, coroutine

In the document here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html, I found many `yield from` can be replaced by `await`.

I was wondering whether they are equivalent all the time in Python 3.5. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. `await` in an `async` function and `yield from` in a generator are very similar and share most of their implementation, but depending on your Python version, trying to use `yield` or `yield from` inside an `async` function will either cause an outright `SyntaxError` or make your function an [asynchronous generator function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/).

When the asyncio docs say "`await` or `yield from`", they mean that `async` functions should use `await` and generator-based coroutines should use `yield from`.